# How can I know my SQLite Table has my desired turple( attribute name )?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I just want to do like that _ I have `OrderTable` and `OrderID`, `OrderItemQty` are save in it. What my problem is , I want to know the order I added is still exist in my database table or not by its `OrderID`. If I add one order that still exist in my database table, I want to add the new `OrderItemQty` on that ( existing Order ) or else add new Order.

Comment: check my answer @KyawLinnThant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method to check if order exists by its Id

```
public boolean IsOrderExists(String orderid)
{
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM OrderTable  where OrderID = '"+orderid+"' ";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Log.d("Log", "Fetching order from Sqlite: " + cursor.getCount());

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
    {
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
       return true; //if found return true
    }
    else
    {
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return false;// if not return false
    }
}
```

in main after initialize db instance do this

```
if(IsOrderFound)
{
    //found update the old qty 
}
else
{
    //not found add new order
}
```